# MySQL - Investigate deadlock on atomic update

Tags: innodb, transaction, deadlock

On a high traffic queue managed by Redis there is the following code:

```
update `ads_publishers` set `impressions` = `impressions` + 1 where `ad_id` = ? and `pub_id` = ?
```

Here's is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads_publishers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ads_publishers_ad_id_index` (`ad_id`),
  KEY `ads_publishers_pub_id_index` (`pub_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ads_publishers_ad_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ad_id`) REFERENCES `campaigns` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ads_publishers_pub_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`pub_id`) REFERENCES `sites` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Lately with an additional traffic increase I start receiving deadlock exceptions on the above query:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The amount is not significant given the traffic, but I would like to know if there is anything I could do about it, instead of just increasing the execution attempts.

The session isolation level is set to `REPEATABLE READ` as far as I know. Should I even think about changing it to `READ_COMMITTED` just for the above transaction or this is to the wrong direction?

Comment: Index on `(ad_id, pub_id)` might help.

Comment: Add the output of `show engine innodb status`'s output to your question. This command will only show the latest deadlock, so ideally you should capture this automatically when a deadlock occurs.

Comment: In addition to what @mustaccio, maybe `(ad_id, pub_id)` should be the primary key (and `remove ads_publishers_ad_id_index`)? Are you ever using `id`? If the traffic queue is redis any reason to not use that for counting? The other sane answer is if deadlock, redo.